# Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.ApplicationClass'

Tags: c#, interop

> **Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.ApplicationClass' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint._Application'**. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{91493442-5A91-11CF-8700-00AA0060263B}' failed due to the following error: Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED)).

I am unable to  finding solution please any one help in this?

Comment: You must reinstall Office on that machine to fix the registry damage.

Comment: Thanks for your response , i reintsalled office but getting same error

Comment: It is the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\TypeLib\{91493440-5A91-11CF-8700-00AA0060263B} registry key, any properly configured machine has it.  Shove that machine out of a 4th story window to make it stop wasting our time.

Comment: I had old 32 bit office installed, I installed office 365 and by default got the 32 bit version.
I had to uninstall all of office and install the new 64bit version of office.

Comment: @Hans Passant I have the casting problem described by the OP, running 64bit PowerPoint. I checked my registry as Hans described above, and 1) the registry key exists, and the path listed under `{91493...}/2.c/0/Win64` was `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\MSPPT.OLB`. The file existed. I don't know how to solve the problem. My code used to work with 32bit office/PowerPoint, but now it works with Word but fails with PowerPoint.

Comment: To be precise, my exception was TYPE_E_ELEMENTNOTFOUND, not TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED.

Comment: @kevin did you solve this problem. If yes, how?

Comment: Sorry, I can't remember, it was so long ago. I know that I had to install and reinstall Office a few times to coordinate the 64bit 32bit apps on my machine.